# Two lines share an invisible xdata in matplotlib with different xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two sets of arrays `x1, y1, t1` and `x2, y2, t1` -- `x` data,  `y` data and time measurement.

I would like to plot two these sets as lines with **time** as an `x` argument in  `plot()`, so that lines are aligned with respect to time precedence of events.

However, I would also like to see the corresponding `x1` and `x2` on the plot in a form of xlabels (say at the top and at the bottom of the plot), as well as have two scales for `y` values (i.e. on the left and on the right of the figure).

```
import numpy as np
t1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y1 = np.arange(10)
x1 = (np.cumsum(np.random.rand(10)) * 1000000000).astype(int)
x1 = (x1 /  100000).astype(int) * 10

x2 = (np.cumsum(np.random.rand(10)) * 1000000000).astype(int)
x2 = (x2 / 1000000).astype(int)
y2 =  2 * np.arange(10)
t2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 10) + 2


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(t1, y1)
ax1.set_ylabel("y1 label")
ax1.set_xticklabels(x1)
ax1.set_xlabel("x1 label")


ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(t2, y2, c='r')
ax2.set_ylabel("y2 label")

ax3 = ax2.twiny()
ax3.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')

ax3.set_xticklabels(x2);
ax3.set_xlabel("x2 label")
```

The code produces 
[image]
which is good, but has two problems:

1. `xlabels` are not aligned with the data: blue line on the plot starts at x1 ticklabel `104500`, while `x1[0] = 29380`.
2. I an unable to apply `sci` format for the `x1` and `x2` ticks, i.e. the line

```
ax1.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
```

fails with `This method only works with the ScalarFormatter`, which is reasonable, since I have replaced labels of ticks, not ticks *themselves*. On the other hand, I cannot assign `x1` to `xticks`, since this will change limits of xaxis.

How could I overcome two these problems?

Comment: `set_xticklabels` is used to set the labels. `set_xticks` is used to set the positions. If you do not set specific positions, your labels will not relate to anything useful. `scilimits` cannot be used when manually setting labels.